# Export document library. Are content types included?

Tags: content-type, export, import

We need to recreate a site from scratch, however we need to keep the data in some document libraries and custom lists.
Therefore, we study the possibility of doing and export-import of the libraries/lists.

The question is, will the content types and sites columns associated to those libraries/lists be preserved in the process ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to migrate a whole site from one location to another. If so, there are a couple of options:

**Option 1:**

Within same SharePoint environment / farm, you can perform export-import using CMP migration option using PowerShell. By using this option, you can retain the contents of the lists and libraries along with the contents types and site columns associated in it. However, this technique has its own limitations and may be out-dated. For more information, please refer the following article:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms481179(v=office.14).aspx

**Option 2:**

Across SharePoint servers, you can use the third party SharePoint migration tools such as Vyapin's [Dockit Migrator for SharePoint](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-migration/dockit/sharepoint-migration-tools), as the CMP technique is not suitable for the migration across SharePoint servers / versions due to it’s inherent limitations.